# Search Range for Value Change, Copy Whole Row if Found

Tags: vba, excel, search, criteria

I'm very new to VBA (~4 days new) and have tried to solve this issue in my usual method, through reading lots of different posts on resources like this and experimenting, but have not been able to quite get the hang of it. I hope you fine folks are willing to point out where I'm going wrong with this. I've looked at a lot (all?) of the  threads with similar issues but haven't been able to cobble together a solution for myself from them. I hope you'll forgive this if it has already been answered somewhere else.

Context:

I've got a spreadsheet with items in rows 5-713 down column B (merged up to cell J) where for each date (Columns K-SP) the item is scored either a 1 or a 0. My goal is to create a list at the bottom of the worksheet that contains all items which have gone from 1 to 0. To start, I've simply been trying to get my "generate list" button to copy all rows with a 0 in them to the bottom, figuring I would tweak it later to do exactly what I wanted. I've tried several things and gotten several different errors.

[Worksheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Won.png) for a visual of what I'm talking about.

I've gone through several different attempts and have had limited success with each, usually getting a different error every time. I've had "method 'range of object' _Worksheet failed", "object required", "type mismatch", "out of memory", and a few others. I'm sure I'm simply not grasping some of the basic syntax, which is causing some problems.

Here is the latest batch of code, giving me the error 'type mismatch'. I've also tried having 'todo' be string but that just shoots out 'object required'

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim y As Integer, z As Integer, todo As Range

Set todo = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(713, 510))

y = 5
z = 714
With todo
    Do
        If todo.Rows(y).Value = 0 Then
        todo.Copy Range(Cells(z, 2))
        y = y + 1
        z = z + 1
        End If
    Loop Until y = 708
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Another attempt I thought was promising was the following, but it gives me 'out of memory'.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim y As Integer, z As Integer

y = 5
z = 714

Do
    If Range("By:SPy").Value = 0 Then
    Range("By:SPy").Copy Range("Bz")
    y = y + 1
    z = z + 1
    End If
Loop Until y = 708

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Just to reiterate, the code attempts I've posted were simply to get any row containing 0's to the bottom of the spreadsheet, however, if there's a way define the criteria to search for 1's that turn to 0's, that would be amazing! Also, I'm not sure how to differentiate a 0 in the actual data and a zero in the item name (for example, it would not be great to have 'Item 10' go into the list just because 10 is a 1 with a 0 after it).

Any help to figure out this first step, or even how to have it scan for 1's that turn to 0's would be wonderfully appreciated. I'm sure I'm missing something simple and hope you guys can forgive my ignorance.

Thanks!

Comment: give an example of what items "have gone from 1 to 0" in your linked worksheet sample

Comment: Item 6 in column AK would be an example of an item that has changed. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: well, you must know that! but please give example of all items that would meet that condition in your worksheet sample

Comment: Again, I'm sorry, I think I'm misunderstanding you. Reading from left to right, any item in the list (from item 1 to item 708) that has a 1 which turns to 0 on another date would want to be flagged. Item 6 in the image is the only example there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks through the data and copies it down below the last row of the data. It is assuming there is nothing below the data. It also only looks for zeros **after** it finds a 1.

```
Sub findValueChange()

    Dim lastRow As Long, copyRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim myCell As Range, myRange As Range, dataCell As Range, data As Range
    Dim hasOne As Boolean, switchToZero As Boolean
    Dim dataSht As Worksheet




    Set dataSht = Sheets("Sheet1") '<---- change for whatever your sheet name is

    'Get the last row and column of the sheet
    lastRow = dataSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
    lastCol = dataSht.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Where we are copying the rows to (2 after last row initially)
    copyRow = lastRow + 2

    'Set the range of the items to loop through
    With dataSht
        Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(lastRow, 2))
    End With

    'start looping through the items
    For Each myCell In myRange
        hasOne = False 'This and the one following are just flags for logic
        switchToZero = False
        With dataSht
            'Get the range of the data (1's and/or 0's in the row we are looking at
            Set data = .Range(.Cells(myCell.row, 11), .Cells(myCell.row, lastCol))
        End With
        'loop through (from left to right) the binary data
        For Each dataCell In data
            'See if we have encountered a one yet
            If Not hasOne Then 'if not:
                If dataCell.Value = "1" Then
                    hasOne = True 'Yay! we found a 1!
                End If
            Else 'We already have a one, see if the new cell is 0
                If dataCell.Value = "0" Then 'if 0:
                    switchToZero = True 'Now we have a zero
                    Exit For 'No need to continue looking, we know we already changed
                End If
            End If
        Next dataCell 'move over to the next peice of data

        If switchToZero Then 'If we did find a switch to zero:
            'Copy and paste whole row down
            myCell.EntireRow.Copy
            dataSht.Cells(copyRow, 2).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            copyRow = copyRow + 1 'increment copy row to not overwrite
        End If

    Next myCell


    'housekeeping
    Set dataSht = Nothing
    Set myRange = Nothing
    Set myCell = Nothing
    Set data = Nothing
    Set dataCell = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that works great! Thank you so much! I may comment again after I look it over to understand what you've done if I have a question about it- hope you don't mind. Thanks again!!

Comment: @burger I'm glad it works. I went ahead and added clarifying comments in my post to help you understand the process. But feel free to ask if something doesn't make sense!